# Kaspersky processing error Explorer.exe (recycle bin)

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I get daily critical errors from Kaspersky involving Explorer.exe...  The file in question is almost always in the Recycle Bin, or something on the desktop.

Here is an example error detail:

```
Event type:     Processing error
Application\Name:       EXPLORER.EXE
Application\Path:       C:\WINDOWS\
Application\Process ID: 2364
Application\Options:    C:\windows\Explorer.EXE
Component:      File Anti-Virus
Result\Description:     Processing error
Object: C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1403139956-787289773-2644151291-500\$RIKKQKS
Object\Type:    File
Object\Path:    C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1403139956-787289773-2644151291-500\
Object\Name:    $RIKKQKS
Reason: Read error
```

Google searches didn't offer much insight, so I thought I'd ask here if anyone has encountered a similar situation.  Not sure if it's a bug, something to be concerned about, or an easy fix, etc.  I usually just empty the recycle bin for a temporary fix, but would like to get to the root of the error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably resort to telling Kaspersky to fix their shit, but a more permanent fix would be to actually delete those files - at least for the Recycle Bin files, the problem is often that the files have broken or missing ACLs, so they're not accessible to system processes, or that the file is actually gone, but the pointer to it isn't.

When I've run into files like this, I'll typically just run a `rmdir /s /q` on the parent directory (because they're not deletable with any other method I've found, and emptying the Recycle Bin doesn't do a damn thing about them either).

If you go into that Recycle Bin path (using the CLI), you'll probably find a bunch of subfolders and files that haven't been properly emptied from the Recycle Bin for whatever reason.  These often cause problems with any application trying to interact with them, and since they're essentially deleted anyway, I've always just finished them off and never run into a problem for doing so.

For example, a couple `.vbs` abominations that got stuck under the Recycle Bin on my workstation, below.  Probably a couple of the horrid scripts the last guy used for *everything* that didn't get purged when I replaced them with GPPs.

[image: Die, VBS.]

Directory removed, problem solved.  When it's one of those top-level UID-style directories, Windows will regenerate it when needed, so no harm done.

Comment: Pretty logical answer and along the lines of what I was thinking as well since the objects included aren't actually visible in the recycle bin most of the time.  Thanks for the insight.  I posted this to kaspersky forums as well, so if a solution arises from that I'll be sure to update this post.

Comment: Not an exact answer to the main problem, but at least offers a good temporary fix for the errors associated with the Recycle Bin.  Thanks for the included screenshot and edit!